# Why can't I interact (fill, click, etc) with this element using Playwright in my Python code?

Tags: python, html, playwright, playwright-python

I'm using Playwright to access and interact with a website and it was going perfect till I found myself in the page where I can't interact any button ou search bar to apply a filter. I can use `.locator('xpath')` to find the elemente, but when I tried `.click('xpath')`, `.fill('xpath')` or even `.locator ('xpath').click()`, I receive the below error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Python Files\join\necessidades\join.py", line 24, in <module>
    pagina.locator('//*[@id="jrhFrm:barFiltro:filtros:nomeDoCurso_hinput"]').click()
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\playwright\sync_api\_generated.py", line 13670, in click
    self._sync(
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_sync_base.py", line 104, in _sync
    return task.result()
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_locator.py", line 146, in click
    return await self._frame.click(self._selector, strict=True, **params)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_frame.py", line 489, in click
    await self._channel.send("click", locals_to_params(locals()))
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_connection.py", line 44, in send
    return await self._connection.wrap_api_call(
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_connection.py", line 419, in wrap_api_call
    return await cb()
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_connection.py", line 79, in inner_send
    result = next(iter(done)).result()
playwright._impl._api_types.TimeoutError: Timeout 30000ms exceeded.
=========================== logs ===========================
waiting for locator("xpath=//*[@id=\"jrhFrm:barFiltro:filtros:nomeDoCurso_hinput\"]")
```

Here's the inspection of the page to ~maybe~ help understand the context. I don't know why the search bar is inside a tag.

[image: PAGE INSPECTION IMAGEy]

Example of my code so far, with the Codegen "suggestion"

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
from time import sleep

with sync_playwright() as p:
    navegador = p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    pagina = navegador.new_page()
    pagina.goto("page_url")
    
    pagina.fill('full_xpath from Username input','USERNAME')
    pagina.fill('full_xpath from Password input', 'Password')
    pagina.click('full_xpath from Enter button')
  
    try:
        pagina.click('full_xpath from a boring pop-up that sometimes shows up')
    except:
        pass
    
    sleep(10) #waiting the page to fully load

    pagina.click('full_xpath from the title of a Menu Item called Trainings')
    pagina.click('full_xpath from an Item called Course List that appeared from the Menu List')

    # HERE'S WHERE I'M HAVING PROBLEM
    sleep(5) #waiting the page to fully load
    pagina.locator('full_xpath from the search bar that I want to fill').fill('text I need to insert to search the Training')

    # THE BELOW CODE WAS GENERATED BY codegen
    pagina.frame_locator("#embedJoinRhJsf").locator("[id=\"jrhFrm\\:barFiltro\\:filtros\\:cursoPesquisa\"]").fill("TEXT") #raise an exception that I posted above in the comments
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve]. There are many reasons why a site might prevent you from seeing an element--iframe, arbitrary dynamic JS behavior, bot detection...

Comment: Are you 100% sure element is on the screen when you try to make click?

Comment: @ggorlen, ok I'll try to bring this example or post my code.

@JakyRuby, I tought 'bout that too, but when I applied sleep to awai the element - using a considerable time - it didn't help. 

Following another suggestion, I used 'codegen' to understand what was the manual operationbehind the curtains and noticed that codegen used `.frame_locator(name).locator(full xpath).click()`. Ironically, the code didn't work out because of the below error.

Comment: playwright._impl._api_types.Error: Selector "#embedJoinRhJsf" resolved to JSHandle@<embed width="100%" height="100%" type="text/html" id="…/>, <iframe> was expected
=========================== logs ===========================
  waiting for frame_locator("#embedJoinRhJsf")
  locator resolved to visible <embed width="100%" height="100%" type="text/html" id="…/>

Comment: @ggorlen, is my edit helpful?

Comment: Sort of and thanks, but I can't run this or see the page so you're still asking us to guess where a needle in a dark room might be. `sleep(10)` is not good practice, prefer `wait_for_function` or `wait_for_selector`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using general CSS selector?
Unsure why your Xpath selector doesn't work, and assuming there's a specific reason you are using xpaths, but by default I usually use general CSS selectors rather than xpaths if I can.  Right click the element and Copy > Selector.
From your pic it looks like it will be "#jrhFRM:barFiltro:filtros:cursoPesquisa"
Thus

```
pagina.locator("#jrhFRM:barFiltro:filtros:cursoPesquisa").click()
```

Hope this works.
Also, check that you have copied the correct xpath, as the id in your error message...

```
"jrhFrm:barFiltro:filtros:nomeDoCurso_hinput"
```

...does not look like it matches the id in your screenshot...

```
"#jrhFRM:barFiltro:filtros:cursoPesquisa"
```

Let us know.

Comment: Hi,, thanks for answering. I'm using the Xpath not for any specific reason, just that I used to it. Anyway, I tried your suggestion and ocorred another error (below). Understanding that this new error is about some unescaped char...right?


=========================== logs ===========================
waiting for locator("#jrhFRM:barFiltro:filtros:cursoPesquisa")
  Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '#jrhFRM:barFiltro:filtros:cursoPesquisa' is not a valid selector.
============================================================

Comment: I don't think it's due to an unescaped character, but it's really difficult to troubleshoot if you're not sharing your code.  Can you perhaps try to share your code in the function where the error occurs?  It may be that the "querySelectorAll' is expecting an array, and only a single item is returned...?